# Webscraping old html script in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to web scrape a site, and I get a problem due to the update of the page I suppose.
And I don't understand how to resolve it.

The information I want to web scrape is the url of each EuroLeague basketball past game.
The global page with games is [here](https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/), and displays the last played games, for example Milan vs Madrid

Let's say I want to web scrape games from 2022 Round 8. I can just do it from the menu, or add it to the url:

```
?round=8season=E2022
```

The page for it is [here](https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/?round=8season=E2022)

For example, in this round, Madrid played against Berlin.

When I get the HTML of this past page, it is the same as the current one as you can see running this code:

```
import pandas as p
import urllib.request
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

current_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/", context = context)
current_bytes = current_url.read()
current_html = current_bytes.decode("utf8")

past_url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/?round=8season=E2022", context = context)
past_bytes = past_url.read()
past_html = past_bytes.decode("utf8")

print(past_html)
print(past_html == current_html)
```

If you search on the past_html text, you can find the string "milan-real-madrid" which is the game from current game and there isn't string like "real-madrid-alba-berlin"

But the madrid-berlin game URL do exist in the HTML code if, from the round 8 / 2022 page on my browser, you click right, then Inspect the page, as you can see on the screenshot (highlighted in yellow):
[image]

Do you know how I can extract it?

---

Edit: I tried with Selenium but it still extracting only last games:

```
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

driver = Chrome() 

url = "https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/euroleague/game-center/?round=8&season=E2022" 
 
driver.get(url) 
anchor_tags = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class*=game-card-view_linkWrap__]")

hrefs = [tag.get_attribute("href") for tag in anchor_tags]

print(hrefs)
```

Comment: Maybe the page content is generated by JavaScript. Since `urllib.request` doesn't support JavaScript you will have to use something different, like "selenium".

Comment: I tried it, but I still get the same outputs, only last games... :-/ I updated my message with the code I worked on...

Comment: what data you exactly want to scrap? can you give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded via Javascript from external URL. Here is an example how you can get the data:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://feeds.incrowdsports.com/provider/euroleague-feeds/v2/competitions/E/seasons/E2022/games?teamCode=&phaseTypeCode=RS&roundNumber=8"

data = requests.get(api_url).json()

# print(data)

for item in data["data"]:
    print(
        f'{item["home"]["name"][:30]:<30} {item["home"]["score"]:^5} - {item["away"]["score"]:^5} {item["away"]["name"][:30]:<30} '
    )
```

Prints:

```
Partizan Mozzart Bet Belgrade   96   -  88   Maccabi Playtika Tel Aviv      
Zalgiris Kaunas                 71   -  62   EA7 Emporio Armani Milan       
AS Monaco                       79   -  74   Cazoo Baskonia Vitoria-Gasteiz 
Fenerbahce Beko Istanbul        107  -  77   Panathinaikos Athens           
Real Madrid                     90   -  72   ALBA Berlin                    
Virtus Segafredo Bologna        89   -  59   Valencia Basket                
FC Bayern Munich                71   -  82   Olympiacos Piraeus             
Crvena Zvezda Meridianbet Belg  71   -  67   LDLC ASVEL Villeurbanne        
Anadolu Efes Istanbul           96   -  86   FC Barcelona
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely, it was exactly what I needed. How did you understand it was updated from an external url?

Comment: @ImFabien75 You should see this URL in your browser in Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab (when you refresh your page)